# properties from resolve object not passing to controller, unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Before voting this down, yes this question has been asked here already, and answered, but the answers are not satisfactory. They all correctly suggest to add the controller in the route configuration, but this is not the case here.

The expected behavior for the routeProvider's `resolve` object `xxx` is to be injected into the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('X', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        controller:'XCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'x.html',
        resolve: {
            xxx: function () {
                return 'XXX from routing config.';
            }
        }
    })
}])
.controller('XCtrl', function($scope, xxx) {
    console.log('xxx = '+xxx);
});
```

The console should get a `xxx = XXX from routing config.` entry.

Instead, the code extract above fails with:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: xxxProvider <- xxx
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=xxxProvider%20%3C-%20xxx
 .. etc.
```

`XCtrl` is not declared in the HTML with a `ng-controller` directive but only defined in the routing configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have several entry in the routing configuration using the same controller, all properties that are injected in the controller must appear in all instances of the `resolve` object:

```
var app = angular.module('X', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        controller:'XCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'x.html',
        resolve: {
            xxx: function () {
                return 'XXX from routing config.';
            }
            another: // ...
        }
    })
    .when('/page2',{
        controller:'XCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'x/p2.html',
        resolve: {
            xxx: function () {
                return 'XXX from routing config.';
            }
        }
    })
}])
.controller('XCtrl', function($scope, xxx) {
    console.log('xxx = '+xxx);
});
```

The `resolve` objects don't have to be promises, straight data returning from a function as above also works. Promises are useful to prevent the routing if one of them is rejected.